# Sending data from react to node by get request using axios library

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, httprequest

for more than 3 hours I'm handling with an issue, what I'm trying to do is sending a get request from react to nodejs using axios library, I wanna pass some data into this request, as we know the get request don't have a body, so I've sent the data as query parameter like that

```
    // base URL
    const url = "http://localhost:8080/loginAsTeacher";
    if(loginAs === "loginTeacher"){
        axios.get(url,{ 
            params :{
                email: "abc123@gmail.com",
                password: "abc1234*"
            }
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res)) // this line return status:200 and data:null
        .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
    }
```

so this request success but the problem is the email and password are not passing to the backend

```
router.get("/loginAsTeacher", async (req,res)=>{
    // values coming from the client
    const loginEmail = req.params.email;
    const loginPassword = req.params.password;
    console.log(req.params); // this line return {} empty object
    // get data of that user by his/her mail
    const teacherData = await myModel.findOne({
        email: loginEmail
    }).exec()
    res.status(200).json({
        status: 200,
        data: teacherData
    })
})
```

the console.log above return an empty object, which means there's no parameters

Is this not the right solution ???

thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your queries you need to get req.query instead of req.params

Btw. it's dangerous to send sensitive data over get. It could be get logged in plaintext even over https

Answer (score 0):

use req.query instead of req.params. it will solve the issue